# Switching between Landscape and Portrait mode using Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I have a very simple application that switches between landscape mode and portrait mode. In portrait mode I have a Fragments that displays data in a list and in landscape mode I have another fragment that displays my data in a grid. Just to re-iterate there are two different fragments, a ListFragment that renders data in portrait mode and a 'GridFragment' that displays data in landscape mode. The individual fragments render correctly as long the device orientation is not changed. The app however crashes the moment the device flips from portrait to landscape or vice-versa.

First here are my error logs.The error log when the device is flipped from portrait mode to landscape:

> 09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.funapp.ssnd/com.funapp.ssnd.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3677)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:149)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:956)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1901)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:567)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1166)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5030)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
>   09-22 11:48:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(29737):    ... 12 more

And the error log when the device changes from landscape to portrait:

> 09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.funapp.ssnd/com.funapp.ssnd.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3677)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:149)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at com.funapp.ssnd.DetailsFragment.onActivityCreated(DetailsFragment.java:59)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1512)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:962)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1103)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1901)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:567)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1166)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5030)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
>   09-22 11:52:20.906: E/AndroidRuntime(29943):    ... 12 more

The Activity that contains the Fragments:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

     if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
         MemberListFragment fragment1 = new MemberListFragment();
         transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment1);
         transaction.commit();
     }

     if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
         DetailsFragment fragment2 = new DetailsFragment();
         transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment2);
         transaction.commit();
     }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Also the layout files. For portrait mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

And for landscape mode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:numColumns="3"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"

/>
```

And the fragments. For portrait mode:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MemberListFragment extends ListFragment {

String[] membersList;
Integer[] imageList;
ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,false);

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    membersList = (getResources().getStringArray(R.array.snsd_members));
    imageList = new Integer[membersList.length];

    for(int i=0; i<membersList.length; i++){

        imageList[i] = R.drawable.home;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<membersList.length; i++){

        RowItem item = new RowItem(imageList[i], membersList[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) getListView();
    SNSDAdapter adapter = new SNSDAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.list_element, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}



}
```

And landscape mode:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

String[] membersList;
Integer[] imageList;
GridView gridView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,false);

    gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    return view;

}  

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    membersList = (getResources().getStringArray(R.array.snsd_members));
    imageList = new Integer[membersList.length];

    for(int i=0; i<membersList.length; i++){

        imageList[i] = R.drawable.home;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<membersList.length; i++){

        RowItem item = new RowItem(imageList[i], membersList[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    Log.v("ROW ITEMS",rowItems.toString());
    GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),rowItems);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

}




}
```

I have spent many hours trying to resolve this without arriving at a solution. Could this be because my Fragments are not really 'destroyed' when the screen is rotated preventing a new fragment from taking its place ? Any solution or some direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: The exceptions come from your fragments' code. Can you show this code as well (the relevant part)?

Comment: @Szymon I added the fragments code as well.

Comment: do you have a line like "android:configChanges="orientation"" in your activity declaration in your manifest?

Comment: @labreu No, I do not have that setting in my manifest.

Comment: Just if it helps to know, if I use a list view in landscape mode and replace one fragment with another, the orientation changes are seamless and the app does not crash. In this case however, a switch from a listview to a gridview (or vice versa) does not give me the expected results. Also in MainActivity, I do not replace any fragments but instead add them every time the device orientation changes. Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: well if the activity is actually reacreated and you'r not retaining the instances that should not be a problem, but your using support library and I've some problems with fragments and support library in the past, so to check you'll have to debug and see what the fragment manager is holding when the orientation change, but for me it seems more like the onCreate not know that the orientation change or something like that

Comment: a suggestion could be try another approach and use only one fragment and refresh the view and not recreate the activity, find references you need here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: but be careful too with that approach, I find that in some phones onConfigurationChanged do weird things

Comment: OK, just to make a test replace the "transaction.add" for "transaction.replace" and if it does not work try "cleaning" the fragment manages before, that means get all the fragments in the fragment manager and remove all

Answer (score 0):

check your `ListView` id in XML file...
It should be `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: When the app renders in portrait mode, it displays a ListView as expected. When the device orientation changes from portrait to landscape it appears as though my activity still expects a list view when in fact a grid view should be rendered instead. Does this mean that my 'list view' fragment is recreated everytime the device orientation changes ? Same applies for changes from landscape mode to portrait mode. It may help to know that the error logs are different for each orientation change.

Comment: may be at Landscape mode the Activity not able to find the ListView..so u just disable the listview in Landscape mode..